# What are all the Qmmp versions?

Tags: version, qmmp

I normally use Kubuntu and Qmmp and end up installing Qmmp from [PPA, like here](https://launchpad.net/%7Eforkotov02/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), linked from [Qmmp site's Downloads](https://qmmp.ylsoftware.com/downloads.php), linked on the main page. [There](https://qmmp.ylsoftware.com/), multiple versions are listed.

[image]

From PPA 1.5.3 is installed.

**What are the other versions? How could I install them?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the download page:

```
>>> qmmp-2.0.3.tar.bz2 [MD5] (stable version for Qt6)
>>> qmmp-1.5.3.tar.bz2 [MD5] (stable version for Qt5)
>>> qmmp-0.12.14.tar.bz2 [MD5] (stable version for Qt4)
```

Makes it abundantly clear what versions exist and why.

With Linux distros you're supposed to install what's offered by your distro repositories. If you're not content with that, you could try FlatPak, Snap or AppImage versions. Lastly you can compile and install everything into `/usr/local` or `/opt/appname`.